# Detecting DST changes in C++

Tags: c++, linux, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I am working on c++ real time application which is doing lot of date manipulations. For performance reasons, I made the UTC offset as configurable value which is read only once at the time of application initialization. But it is causing issues in DST zones.

When DST Changes happens, My UTC offset variable contain wrong value. 
Calculating the Offset every time is not a optimal solution for me.

So is there anyway to notify my application about DST changes? So I can calculate the offset only when it need to modified.

Comment: You need two settings: The region or country, which decides when the DST changes happen. And the current time zone, which defines the standard time offset from UTC. If DST is in effect (known from the first setting), add one hour to the current local time (as calculated by the time zone). However, once you've done all that, then throw your code code handling time and time zones. Time and date is much harder than it seems, so I really recommend you try to find a library which will handle it all for you.

Comment: will that help? https://superuser.com/questions/294984/how-to-make-an-application-detect-if-system-time-has-changed-in-linux

Comment: About the calculating offset part: you can calculate the timestamp of the next DST change and cache it. Then every time you use the time, you just compare it to cached timestamp. If lower, DST didn't change, if higher, update your offset and compute next DST change.

Answer (score 2):

Using the draft C++20 `<chrono>` facilities you can discover the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` for the next UTC offset change for *any* time zone, and then `std::this_thread::sleep_until` that `time_point`.  When you wake, do whatever it is you want to do, such as compute a new UTC offset.

The new draft C++20 `<chrono>` library has been prototyped and is [available as a free, open-source library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) under `namespace date`.  This library is portable across VS, gcc and clang, and operates with C++11 and later.

Here is a sketch of how this might be coded:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <thread>

template <class F>
void
on_utc_offset_change(date::time_zone const* tz, F f)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    while (true)
    {
        auto info = tz->get_info(system_clock::now());
        f(info);
        this_thread::sleep_until(info.end);
    }
}
```

A [`time_zone`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#time_zone) has a `get_info(system_clock::time_point)` member function that returns a [`sys_info`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#sys_info).  The [`sys_info`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#sys_info) contains all information about a [`time_zone`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#time_zone) for a particular point in time:

```
struct sys_info
{
    sys_seconds          begin;
    sys_seconds          end;
    std::chrono::seconds offset;
    std::chrono::minutes save;
    std::string          abbrev;
};
```

The `begin` and `end` members are `seconds`-precision `system_clock` `time_point`s that delineate the range `[begin, end)` for which this `time_zone` has this UTC `offset` and abbreviation (`abbrev`).

This function might be called like this:

```
auto lambda = [](date::sys_info const& info)
              {
                  using namespace date;
                  std::cerr << "Current UTC offset: " << info.offset << '\n';
                  std::cerr << "Current tz abbreviation: " << info.abbrev << '\n';
                  std::cerr << "Sleeping until " << info.end << " UTC\n";
              };
std::thread{on_utc_offset_change<decltype(lambda)>,
            date::current_zone(),
            lambda}.detach();
```

This detaches a `thread` that runs forever and every time the UTC offset changes for the computer's current `time_zone` (at the time the thread was launched), it prints out current information, for example.

```
Current UTC offset: -14400s
Current tz abbreviation: EDT
Sleeping until 2018-11-04 06:00:00 UTC
```

Alternatively you could run this for a specific `time_zone` which is not the computer's currently set `time_zone` with:

```
std::thread{on_utc_offset_change<decltype(lambda)>,
            date::locate_zone("America/New_York"),
            lambda}.detach();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have the choice to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: Not even to C++11?!  My sincerest condolences.